glutBitmapCharacter worked in older version but no longer
I am reviving some legacy OpenGL code from 2004. Somewhere along the way, the display of lettering quit working.  glutBitmapCharacter does not work, it fails silently and nothing appears. Obviously something has subtly shifted in the libraries in 20 years.  Code using BeginDataStrip / EndDataStrip displays as it always has, but anything involving glutBitmapCharacter is invisible.
Here is a small test program that demonstrates that same problem. Please, what would it take to get the letter 'A' as specified on line 45 to actually appear?
Environment: MacOS 14.2.1, VSCode 1.98.1, llvm toolchain.
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H>
#include <FL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>

void glutWireSphere (GLdouble radius, GLint slices, GLint stacks);

class MyGlWindow : public Fl_Gl_Window {
private:
    float blue;
public:
    MyGlWindow(int x, int y, int w, int h, float bblue = 0.0f, 
                const char* l = 0) : Fl_Gl_Window(x, y, w, h, l) {
        blue = bblue;
    }

    void draw() override {
        if (!valid()) {
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glViewport(0, 0, w(), h());
            glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 5.0);
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            valid(1);
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        // Set up the camera
        gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 4.5,  // eye position
                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  // look-at position
                  0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // up direction

        // Draw a sphere
        glColor3f(0.5, 1.0, blue);
        glutWireSphere(0.8, 20, 20);
        // NOT WORKING:
        glRasterPos2f(0.5, 0.4);
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, 'A');

        glFlush();
    }
};

int main() {
    Fl_Window* window = new Fl_Window(400, 800, "FLTK Sphere Example");
    MyGlWindow* glWindow = new MyGlWindow(10, 20, window->w() - 20, 400 - 20, 0.0);
    window->resizable(window);
    window->end();
    window->show();
//    Fl_Widget * const *kids = tab1.array();
    return Fl::run();
}


Replace:
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
by:
#include <FL/glu.h>
#include <FL/glut.H>

Has Glut.h had its directory changed? I notice that the original question has no suggestion that the code doesn't compile.

The FLTK docs say in https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/glut.html : Using the GLUT Compatibility Header File: You should be able to compile existing GLUT source code by including <FL/glut.H> instead of <GL/glut.h>.
... which means: you need to include the FLTK (glut emulation) header to work with FLTK's glut emulation.
